# AncestorLevel not working when binding to the view model of parent window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, multibinding

MainWindow is bound to `MainViewModel` and the rest are all bound to `ChildViewModel` which is a property of `MainViewModel`. Now in the innermost child window, which is bound to `ChildViewModel`, I want to bind a property to `MainViewModel`.

I'm using the following code:

Here the first value of the `Converter` is bound to property `C` in `ChildViewModel` and it works. I have tried to bind the second value to a property to the DataContext of `MainWindow` (`MainViewModel`) with no success.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UnitConverter}">
    <Binding Path="C"/>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type Window}, AncestorLevel=2}"
             Path="DataContext.CurrentTargetUnit"/>
</MultiBinding>

--- Main Window -------------------------------------------
-   ----- User Control 1 -------------------------------  -
-   -   ---- User Control 2--------------------------  -  -
-   -   -   ------ Child Window 1 ----------------  -  -  -
-   -   -   -   ----- Child Window 2 ----------  -  -  -  -
-   -   -   -   -                             -  -  -  -  -
-   -   -   -   -   [Bind to MainViewModel]   -  -  -  -  -
-   -   -   -   -                             -  -  -  -  -
-   -   -   -   -------------------------------  -  -  -  -
-   -   -   --------------------------------------  -  -  -
-   -   ---------------------------------------------  -  -
-   ----------------------------------------------------  -
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update:**

My best guess is that one only can bind to the parent window and not higher than that. Maybe the uppermost window is not in the visual tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property on the `ChildViewModel` which is a referential link to the `MainViewModel`. Upon the instantiation of the child VM, link it to the `MainViewModel`. Then the internal windows/controls can get to the `MainViewModel` by referencing the aformentioned `ChildViewModel` property to the main vm.

---

On the User Control1 and 2 create a dependency property of the main view model's type such as:

```
// <summary>
/// Holds the parent VM here.
/// </summary>
public MainVM ParentVM
{
    get { return GetValue(ParentVMProperty) as MainVM; }
    set { SetValue(ParentVMProperty, value); }
}

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the ParentVM dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly System.Windows.DependencyProperty ParentVMProperty =
        System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ParentVM",
            typeof(MainVM),
            typeof({Insert Control1 or 2 class type here}),
            new System.Windows.PropertyMetadata(null, OnParentVMPropertyChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// ParentVMProperty property changed handler.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">BeginRandom that changed its ParentVM.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
    private static void OnParentVMPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var source = d as {Insert Control1 or 2 class type here};
        MainVM value = e.NewValue as MainVM;
    }
```

Since each window will have a reference available to the MainWindowVM, all you have to do is path to the current window's `ParentVM` property.

---

Note that to create control's dependency properties I use the handy snippets, written for Silverlight, but **all of them** work in WPF:

[Helpful Silverlight Snippets - Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/)

Comment: It didn't work. It seems it doesn't recognize the parent window this way. I used this to also verify with no success. `<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyWindowName, Path=Title}" Height="28"  />`

Comment: @Vahid how does the main window instantiate the child windows?

Comment: The view model of the `MainWindow` is instantiated in the code behind and then I have user controls in the `MainWindow` that their data contexts are instantiated in XAML and passed to child windows in code-behind. So far everything is working very well apart from this issue that I can't recognize the parent window. I can recognize `Child Window 1` from `Child Window 2` though but no upper.

Comment: @Vahid see updated answer about putting a property on the `ChildViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks OmegaMan, actually this is the hack I'm using right now to get the things done! But honestly shouldn't be a better way to do this? I cannot think of any reason why `AncestorLevel` is not working. I have tried with different levels but still not working!

Comment: @Vahid I believe that at the level of the child window is, is that *it's* logical tree does not include a direct route *what we see* in the visual tree; hence the failure.

Comment: @Vahid the other way is to create a Dependency property on the control which is of the `MainViewModel`'s type and access it that way.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? I'm really interested in this.

Comment: @Vahid You will need to put in the appropriate plumbing, but by having each control having the VM assigned should pipe it through to the child control.

Comment: Thank you very much OmegaMan, I think I will stick with method one for now, Because this way I won't need to define these dependency properties for each user control.